nvme timeout issues on new Intel 7-155H laptop - kernel 6.5 OEM
I have a new laptop with an Intel 7-155H processor and an nvme SSD. I'm running Linux Mint 21.3 and having storage issues. On initial installation the entire system was very slow to do all operations. I upgraded to the 6.5.0-1023-oem kernel and things improved significantly. However, whenever I do a moderate amount of read/writes the entire system freezes, except for the mouse cursor, for about a minute. The dmesg output shows multiple messages like:
nvme nvme0: I/O 97 QID 1 timeout, completion polled

How can I find the root cause of this and resolve it?

Any news on this. Same problem for me with latest kernel.

The only other update I have is that I ended up swapping the SSD into another system and installing a new SSD in the troubled system. The original SSD worked fine in another system, and the new SSD worked fine in the new system without the hack below. I assume this means it's an issue with the specific combination of kernel, NVME controller, and SSD.

If can help anyone I solved disabling VMD. see: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=219220

While it's not a complete solution, I have found a temporary workaround that makes the system usable and may help others.
You'll find posts online suggesting to adjust nvme.poll_queues to a high number (as high as 64), but this will actually throw an error on certain kernels as being an invalid option. The highest I could successfully set this option to is 16; while it will accept 20, it will then fail to find the disk during the LUKS decrypt step. My assumption is because 20 is the maximium number of queues supported, so there are no queues available to handle normal read requests if they're all being used for polling.
Using the commonly recommended nvme.poll_queues=4 doesn't make a significant difference alone, because the system still freezes up for 30 seconds every time an item is queued. Using the queues in conjunction with a very short timeout has resulted in a snappy system where at most I have a 1 second freeze when doing a large file copy. So far I haven't seen any adverse affects from this.
Here's my current GRUB configuration:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0 nvme.poll_queues=4 nvme_core.io_timeout=1"

Any news on this? Dame problemi for me

I just purchased a Acer Swift Go with one of these u7-155h processors (WD sn740 nvme) and had the same issue.
I installed the latest BIOS (1.14) which solved the problem. The timeouts are gone. Download the IRST drv and install a MS-DOS-based OS to flash the firmware :(
